# Complete problem in $\Sigma_2^p$ - $\Sigma_{2}SAT$

Tags: complexity-classes, polynomial-hierarchy

It is known that the following problem is complete in $\Sigma_2^p$:

$\Sigma_{2}SAT$ : Given a quantified boolean formula $\theta = \exists x_1,...,x_l\forall y_1,...,y_m\psi$, where $\psi$ is a boolean propositional formula over the variables $x_1,...,x_l,y_1,...,y_m$ , is $\theta$ valid?

Is it still complete when it is assumed that $\psi$ is in CNF?

It is mentioned in "Computational Complexity: A Modern
Approach" by Sanjeev Arora and Boaz Barak that it can be assumed, but no proof is given:
[https://www.iith.ac.in/~subruk/4510/phchap_arora.pdf](https://www.iith.ac.in/%7Esubruk/4510/phchap_arora.pdf)
(Example 5.9)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Since universal quantifiers commute with conjunctions, it is easy to see that $\Sigma_2$-SAT with $\psi$ CNF is in NP. If it's really written like this in the book, it's an error.

However, the problem is $\Sigma_2$-complete for $\psi$ a 3-DNF.

Comment: In the book (OP has a link to its draft) the error is in Example 5.6.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know a reference for completeness when assuming $\phi$ is in 3-DNF?

Comment: @Naama Shamash Hal: Celia Wrathall ("Complete sets and the polynomial hierarchy", Theoret. Comp. Sci., 3:23-33, 1976) proves completness for DNF-formulas in Corollary 6 on page 32; the step from DNF to 3-DNF is straightforward.